# how to add Row id in pySpark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file; which i convert to DataFrame(df) in pyspark; after some transformation; I want to add a column in df; which should be simple row id (starting from 0 or 1 to N).

I converted df in rdd and use "zipwithindex". I converted resulting rdd back to df. this approach works but it generated 250k tasks and takes a lot of time in execution. I was wondering if there is other way to do it which takes less runtime.

following is snippet of my code; the csv file I am processing is BIG; contains billions of rows.

```
debug_csv_rdd = (sc.textFile("debug.csv")
  .filter(lambda x: x.find('header') == -1)
  .map(lambda x : x.replace("NULL","0")).map(lambda p: p.split(','))
  .map(lambda x:Row(c1=int(x[0]),c2=int(x[1]),c3=int(x[2]),c4=int(x[3]))))

debug_csv_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(debug_csv_rdd)
debug_csv_df.registerTempTable("debug_csv_table")
sqlContext.cacheTable("debug_csv_table")

r0 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT c2 FROM debug_csv_table WHERE c1 = 'str'")
r0.registerTempTable("r0_table")

r0_1 = (r0.flatMap(lambda x:x)
    .zipWithIndex()
    .map(lambda x: Row(c1=x[0],id=int(x[1]))))

r0_df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(r0_2)
r0_df.show(10)
```

Answer (score 90):

You can use also use a function from sql package. It will generate a unique id, however it will not be sequential as it depends on the number of partitions. I believe it is available in Spark 1.5 +

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonicallyIncreasingId

# This will return a new DF with all the columns + id
res = df.withColumn("id", monotonicallyIncreasingId())
```

---

Edit: 19/1/2017

As commented by [@Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086578/how-to-add-row-id-in-pyspark-dataframes#comment67136012_35948427)

Use `monotonically_increasing_id()` instead from Spark 1.6 and on

Comment: In my scenario the resulting row ID's have been all of the same value. All 1.

Comment: @Matthias it worked well for me

Comment: use `monotonically_increasing_id` instead for Spark 1.6 +

Comment: @Matthias See edit

Comment: Note that this doesn't really answer the question as OP is asking for 0-(N-1) indices. monotonically_increasing_id doesn't guarantee consecutive ids.

Comment: By consecutive, I meant to say contiguous.