# Adding a column to a Dataset<Row> using withColumn()..giving issue... missing from in operator !Project

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I am usally able to get a new dataset by adding new column to an existing dataset using `withColumn`. 
But I am not sure why this case is giving error.

```
Dataset<Row> inputDSAAcolonly = inputDSAA.select(colNameA);
Dataset<Row> inputDSBBcolonly = inputDSBB.select(colNameB);
inputDSBBcolonly.withColumn(colNameA, inputDSAAcolonly.apply(colNameA)).show();
```

where `inputDSSAAcolonly` is

```
+----+
|Exer|
+----+
|Some|
|None|
|None|
|None|
```

and `inputDSSBBColonly` is

```
+-----+
|Smoke|
+-----+
|Never|
|Regul|
|Occas|
|Never|
```

Basically  single columns in the datasets.

I need a DS with 2 columns side by side.
`withColumn` has worked but this throwing error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
>   resolved attribute(s) Exer#7 missing from Smoke#47 in operator
>   !Project [Smoke#47, Exer#7 AS Exer#112];;!Project [Smoke#47, Exer#7 AS
>   Exer#112]

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to join the two datasets.

withColumn works on a dataframe with operations on the columns of the dataframe. You are trying to do operations on a different dataframe.

If indeed the issue is as simple as your code, then you can select both and do the relevant operations while both are used. Otherwise you would need to do a join

Comment: Agree with @Assaf. 
See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508489/spark-add-dataframe-column-to-another-dataframe-merge-two-dataframes).

Comment: ..have been using it without zip or adding an index column with both the datasets...  say I am able to do this...                                        Dataset<Row> dswithColAAandTotal=dswithColAA.withColumn("Total", dswithColAA.col(colnames[0]));
     dswithColAAandTotal.show();  works fine giving me ColAA and a calculated column Total....

Comment: where dswithColAA was arrived as below from a Dataset<Row>..  DSvaluesonly.createOrReplaceTempView("tmpTableAA");
String SQLQueryAA="select * from tmpTableAA";
Dataset<Row> dswithColAA=sqlctx.sql(SQLQueryAA).toDF();

Comment: I tried to convert to DF() .,..but below doesn't work....  inputDSAAcolonly.createOrReplaceTempView("ColAA");
     String SQLQueryColumnAA="select * from ColAA";
     Dataset<Row> colAADF=sqlctx.sql(SQLQueryColumnAA).toDF();
     inputDSBBcolonly.createOrReplaceTempView("ColBB");
     String SQLQueryColumnBB="select * from ColBB";
     Dataset<Row> colBBDF=sqlctx.sql(SQLQueryColumnBB).toDF();
     Dataset<Row> ColAABB=colAADF.withColumn(colNameB, colBBDF.apply(colNameB));ColAABB.show() throws error ..

Comment: Unless the data comes from the SAME original dataframe with two different filters you will have to do a join. All the things you try use different dataframes with no relation between them.

Comment: @Binu : If you are okay with above, please care  vote-up/accept answer as owner to close.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dataset<Row> inputDS=spark.read().option("header", false).
            option("inferSchema",true).csv("data/irisAA.csv");
    inputDS.show(4);
    String colAname=inputDS.columns()[0];
    log.error(colAname);
    String colBname=inputDS.columns()[1];
    log.error(colBname);
    Dataset<Row> DSColA=inputDS.select(inputDS.col(colAname));
    DSColA.show(4);
    Dataset<Row> DSColB=inputDS.select(inputDS.col(colBname));
    DSColB.show(4);
    Dataset<Row> DSColAandColA=DSColA.withColumn("Addt_Column", inputDS.col(colAname));
    DSColAandColA.show(4);
    /*Dataset<Row> DSColAandColB=DSColA.withColumn("Addt_Column", inputDS.col(colBname));
    DSColAandColB.show(4); //THIS FAILS........STILL DON'T GET WHY */
    Dataset<Row>  DSColAwithIndex=DSColA.withColumn("df1Key", monotonically_increasing_id());
    DSColAwithIndex.show(4);
    Dataset<Row>  DSColBwithIndex=DSColB.withColumn("df2Key", monotonically_increasing_id());
    DSColBwithIndex.show(4);
    DSColAwithIndex.join(DSColBwithIndex).show(4);
    DSColA.join(DSColB).show(4);
    Dataset<Row> DSwithJoinofTwo=DSColAwithIndex.join(DSColBwithIndex, col("df1Key").equalTo(col("df2Key")), "inner");
    DSwithJoinofTwo.show(4);
    Dataset<Row> DSwithJointrimmed=DSwithJoinofTwo.drop(DSwithJoinofTwo.apply("df1Key")).drop(DSwithJoinofTwo.apply("df2Key"));
    DSwithJointrimmed.show(4); //JOINED DATASET FINALLY OF COLUMN A AND COLUMN B FROM SAME OR DIFF. DATASETS
```

Comment: used withcolumn to add a column

Comment: used join to add the datasets by adding an index column to each and using inner join... withcolumn seems to work if you are trying to create a dataset with additional columns where the columns depend on a column of the same dataset...like Assaf suggested.. I will explore and try to  understand withColumn usage and limitations better..for now above should be ok i guess...Thank you...