# add one column including values from 1 to n in dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I am creating a dataframe with pyspark, like this:

```
+----+------+
|   k|     v|
+----+------+
|key1|value1|
|key1|value1|
|key1|value1|
|key2|value1|
|key2|value1|
|key2|value1|
+----+------+
```

I want to add one 'rowNum' column using 'withColumn' method, the result of dataframe changed like this:

```
+----+------+------+
|   k|     v|rowNum|
+----+------+------+
|key1|value1|     1|
|key1|value1|     2|
|key1|value1|     3|
|key2|value1|     4|
|key2|value1|     5|
|key2|value1|     6|
+----+------+------+
```

the range of rowNum is from 1 to n, n is equal to number of raws. I modified my code, like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
w = Window().partitionBy("v").orderBy('k')
my_df= my_df.withColumn("rowNum", F.rowNumber().over(w))
```

But, I got error message:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'rowNumber'
```

I replaced rowNumber() method with row_number, the above code can run. But, When I run code:

```
my_df.show()
```

I got error message again:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o898.showString.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: row_number()
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable$class.doGenCode(Expression.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.DeclarativeAggregate.doGenCode(interfaces.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:101)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

Comment: This is a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086578/how-to-add-row-id-in-pyspark-dataframes) most likely.

Answer (score 6):

Solution in Spark 2.2:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,lit
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
df = df.withColumn("rowNum", row_number().over(w))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you require require a sequential `rowNum` value from 1 to n, rather than a `monotonically_increasing_id` you can use `zipWithIndex()`

Recreating your example data as follows:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('key1','value1'),
                      ('key1','value1'),
                      ('key1','value1'),
                      ('key1','value1'),
                      ('key1','value1'),
                      ('key1','value1')])
```

You can then use `zipWithIndex()` to add an index to each row. The `map` is used to reformat the data and to add 1 to the index so it starts at 1.

```
rdd_indexed = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1]+1))
df = rdd_indexed.toDF(['id','score','rowNum'])
df.show()


+----+------+------+
|  id| score|rowNum|
+----+------+------+
|key1|value1|     1|
|key1|value1|     2|
|key1|value1|     3|
|key1|value1|     4|
|key1|value1|     5|
|key1|value1|     6|
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: I need to base on current dataframe to add this new column. So, I hope use  the withColumn method of dataframe.

Comment: The `rdd` can be accessed by using `df.rdd` allowing you to use the same concept.  Please note that I would recommend the used of  is to use `monotonically_increasing_id` in combination with `withColumn` although this approach doesn't guarantee sequential ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `windows`

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rowNumber
w = Window().orderBy()
your_df= your_df.withColumn("rowNum", rowNumber().over(w))
```

Here **your_df** is data frame in which you need this column.

Comment: I used your code to try in my program. I found some problems: 'module' object has no attribute 'rowNumber' . So, I found the other method row_number. The row_number can run. But, when I run the code: your_df.show(). I got error message. like this: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: row_number()

Comment: Did you imported rowNumber

Comment: And these statements are 100℅ accurate as I used in my production code

Comment: What version of Spark are you both using, @IvanLee and RakesKumar ?

Comment: I am using spark 2.1, I am trying to fix this problem. I think this is matter of different version.

Comment: I am using  spark 1.6

Comment: I am sure the reason of this problem is matter of different version. I am using spark 2.1. My code is correctly running with row_number method.

Answer (score 1):

I have used spark2.2 and found "`row_number()`" working.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

win_row_number = Window.orderBy("col_name")
df_row_number = df.select("col_name", F.row_number().over(win_row_number))
```