# PySpark - Get index of row from UDF

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions, row-number

I have a dataframe, I need to get the row number / index of the specific row. I would like to add a new row such that it includes the Letter as well as the row number/index  eg. "A - 1","B - 2"

```
#sample data
a= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("A", 20), ("B", 30), ("D", 80)],["Letter", "distances"])
```

with output

```
+------+---------+
|Letter|distances|
+------+---------+
|     A|       20|
|     B|       30|
|     D|       80|
+------+---------+
```

I would like the new out put to be something like this,

```
+------+---------------+
|Letter|distances|index|
+------+---------------+
|     A|       20|A - 1|
|     B|       30|B - 2|
|     D|       80|D - 3|
+------+---------------+
```

This is a function I have been working on

```
def cate(letter):
    return letter + " - " + #index
a.withColumn("index", cate(a["Letter"])).show()
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948427/3433323) can help? (create ids and then pass the row id as argument to your function `cate`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to achieve the result using UDF (only) let's try this

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

#sample data
a= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("A", 20), ("B", 30), ("D", 80)],["Letter", "distances"])

def cate(letter, idx):
    return letter + " - " + str(idx)
cate_udf = udf(cate, StringType())
a = a.withColumn("temp_index", monotonically_increasing_id())
a = a.\
    withColumn("index", cate_udf(a.Letter, a.temp_index)).\
    drop("temp_index")
a.show()
```

Output is:

```
+------+---------+--------------+
|Letter|distances|         index|
+------+---------+--------------+
|     A|       20|         A - 0|
|     B|       30|B - 8589934592|
|     D|       80|D - 8589934593|
+------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: monotonically_increasing_id() doesn't give you the sequence starting from a given value, rather it gives a random sequence.

Comment: @Bala - yeah true... but it's increasing so for OP's use case I think it can be used as an sequential index.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 20), ("B", 30), ("D", 80)],["Letter", "distances"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql("select concat(Letter,' - ',row_number() over (order by Letter)) as num, * from df").show()

+-----+------+---------+                                                        
|  num|Letter|distances|
+-----+------+---------+
|A - 1|     A|       20|
|B - 2|     B|       30|
|D - 3|     D|       80|
+-----+------+---------+
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however I am constrained to using UDF's for pyspark.